# Hard system of equations for real numbers

Tags: systems-of-equations, real-numbers

$\begin{cases}
x+\frac{3x-y}{x^2+y^2}=3 \\
y-\frac{x+3y}{x^2+y^2}=0
\end{cases}$

I supposed that $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}=u$. Then I develop and find the equation $(u+1)(x-y)+3u(x+y)=3$. But I got stuck. Anybody have an idea?

Comment: __Hint:__ Complex numbers.

Comment: You can view the solutions here - https://brilliant.org/problems/most-beautiful-problem/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution via complex numbers - https://brilliant.org/problems/most-beautiful-problem/

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Hint:Write $$\frac{x+3y}{3-x}=x^2+y^2$$ and $$\frac{x+3y}{y}=(x^2+y^2)$$ so $$\frac{3x-y}{3-x}=\frac{x+3y}{y}$$
From here we get
$$3x+9y-6xy=x^2-y^2$$ and you can eliminate one variable.
$$x=\frac{1}{2}(3-6y\pm\sqrt{9+40y^2})$$

Comment: I'ld love to see the rest of your solution, go forth, please.